# Get returning value of a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, javafx, task

I defined in Java the following task and thread:

```
private class FinderTask extends Task<mytype>{
   public FinderTask(){
      ...
   };

   @Override
   protected mytype call() throws Exception {

      mytype t = new mytype();
      ...
      return t;
   }
}
```

Starting thread

```
MainController.FinderTask task = new myClass.FinderTask();
task.runningProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
   @Override 
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean wasRunning, Boolean isRunning) {
            if (!isRunning) {

                System.out.println("task finished");
            }
          }
        });

final Thread thread = new Thread(task , "finder");
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

How can I get the returning value of the call function?

Comment: There is no standard Java class called `Task`. Please share the code of this class or correct your code example. Did you mean [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)? Please also note that Java class names should really be `CamelCase` otherwise you start to confuse people.

Comment: I think you are confusing a lot of concepts here. Namely Callable, Future and the Observer pattern.

Comment: @Duncan, I'm using javafx concurrent task http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use task.getValue(); this will be set before the state of the task transitions to SUCCEEDED; so it will work in the if clause in the listener (you'll need to make your task final to do that).

The value is also an observable property, so you can also do

```
task.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Task>() {
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends mytype> obs, mytype oldValue, mytype newValue) {
    if (newValue != null) {
      System.out.println("Result of task "+newValue);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run it like this, i.e. a plain thread, see the `get()` methods inheritted by `FutureTask` ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)). It may be more appropriate to use the `Service` class ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html)) as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) or Java's standard concurrency (e.g. executors).

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `call` method of `FinderTask` record the information it needs to return in a local instance variable - adding a getter for that variable would make the result accessable.

Alternatively, you could create a `Queue` and pass it to the `FinderTask` on construction. When the `call` method is called just push your result into the queue. You can then just keep hold of the other end of the queue and listen for the result. Very effective if you use a `BlockingQueue` because you can use a listen method that blocks until the result is available.

Comment: Note that if you do this, the local instance variable will be updated from the background thread on which the task's call method is executing. This will make it unsuitable for updating the UI, which can only be updated from the JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: @James_D - Surely the result can be read out of the object in any thread you like. Here I recommend either storing it in an object or in a blocking queue - you can read from the object/queue form any thread you like.

Comment: (Sorry for the delay in replying.)
No, this is not guaranteed to work; at least not without using some synchronization primitives. The Java Language Spec allows the JVM to make all sorts of optimizations that may prevent updates made to a variable in one thread being visible in another thread, unless synchronization is used. Josh Bloch's "Effective Java" and Brian Goetz' "Java Concurrency in Practice" are excellent resources for this.
Passing an object to a BlockingQueue will work, as the BlockingQueue implementation takes care of the low-level synchronization.

Comment: @James_D - I would have made the variable `volatile` but assumed OP would know that.

Comment: That works, of course. Given the amount of misunderstanding about threading in Java, that may be a rash assumption (no offense intended to OP; just a general statement about how many programmers don't get this right). The Task and Service classes provide direct functionality for working on the FX Application thread in order to avoid application programmers having to get their hands dirty with synchronized and volatile primitives.